# How to find a specific row by values in jQuery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to find a specific row by value within a datatables table out of a modal window. 
I was looking on https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector but as I understand it's all based on selectors or internal IDs.
In my case I have 2 columns where I want to be able to lookup for the specific row to update the record after ajax request.

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.status_id > 0) {
                    alert(data.info);
                } else {
                    alert(data.info);
                }
                contractsTable.row.add(dataJSON).draw(false);
         }
```

**EDIT**

Here my code now - I've built my own unique [rowid](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId) and used [selector by id](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector)

Retrieving the data object

```
...
var d = datatable.row(this).data();
... set form values and so on
```

Save and Refresh datatable

```
$('#contractEditSave').on('click', function (e) {

        dataJSON = {
            id: $('#contractEditForm').data('contractid'),
            member_id: $('#contractEditForm').data('memberid'),
            member_name: $('#contractEditModalTitle').text(),
            box_id: $('#contractBox').val(),
            name: $('#contractName').val(),
            description: $('#contractDescription').val(),
            start: $('#contractStart').val(),
            end: $('#contractEnd').val(),
            amount: $('#contractAmount').val(),
            unit: $('#contractUnit').val(),
            max: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/save',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status_id == 0)
                    datatable.row('#' + dataJSON.id).data(dataJSON); //if update
                    ...
                } else {
                    datatable.row.add(dataJSON).draw(false); //if insert
                    ...
                }



                $("#contractEditModal").modal('hide');

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: A `search()` is the way to find specific rows by value. Please elaborate what you mean by "find" and "specific row" and "value". Code is more than appreciated.

Comment: I've added some code to get the purpose

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`fnFindCellRowIndexes`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnFindCellRowIndexes) to find row index holding certain data in given column.

Then you can use [`cell().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) API method to update the cell.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var rowId = $('#example').dataTable()
   .fnFindCellRowIndexes('Angelica Ramos', 0);

table
   .cell(rowId, 0)
   .data('Angelica Ramos (UPDATED)')
   .draw(false);
```

Please note that you need to include `fnFindCellRowIndexes.js` in addition to jQuery DataTables CSS/JS files.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv7st527/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Seems to be the most beneficial solution. Either way, you'll have to add some filtering yourself.

Comment: Absolutely perfect answer ... 
What I've done though is to create a surrogate id out of my 2 values and set it to the rowid option. Then I'm using the wonderful row(string rowid) function to determine the row and passes the data as an object (which I had to parse to set the modal form values) to the .data() function - works perfect!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working properly with the newest version of DataTables. Maybe the plugin hasn't been updated.

Comment: fnFindCellRowIndexes is legacy and does not work with the latest datatables version, and is no longer recommended.  See here:  https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27249/how-can-i-use-the-plugin-fnfindcellrowindexes-in-the-version-1-10-6

Answer (score 4):

I found the fnFindCellRowIndexes plugin to be unbelievably slow, because it calls fnGetData on every cell, which itself is a terrible CPU hog. The answer turns out to be a lot simpler, and orders of magnitude faster to run. The data() of every column, or the whole table, *is already ordered by the sorted column when you request it.* So literally, all you have to do is request column(c).data() and iterate through that array looking for whatever you're looking for, and the indexes will match the row number as currently sorted. In Typescript this is basically like:

```
public findRows(s:string,col:number):number[] {
    let r:number[] = [];
    let dat:any = $('#example').DataTable().column(col).data();
    let len:number = dat.length;
    for (let k=0;k < len;k++) {
        if ((<string>dat[k]).toLowerCase().includes(s.toLowerCase())) r.push(k);
    }
    return r;
}
```